# Let X be a topological space. a) If X is Hausdorff and it has an countable base, so X is normal?

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces, second-countable, first-countable

Let X be a topological space.

a) If X is  Hausdorff  and it has an countable base, so X is normal?

b) If X is regular, and if each point of X has a fundamental countable neighborhood system and is separable, then is X normal?

---

Being normal means that X is $T_1$ and $T_4$.

We say that:

X is $T_4$ if for any A, B $ \subset $ X closed there are U, V $ \subset $ X open disjoint such that A $ \subset $ U and B $ \subset $ V.

X is regular if X is $ T_3 $ and $ T_1 $.

X is $ T_3 $ iff for each x $ \in $ X and each F $ \subset $ X closed such that x $ \notin $ F there are U, V $ \subset $ X open disjoint such that x $ \in $ U and F $ \subset $ V.

If X is $T_3$ is $T_2$ and $T_1$.

If X is $T_2$ is also $T_1$.

if X is Separable it contains a subset A where for any point x in X, any neighborhood of x contains at least one point from A and A is countable. (A space is called separable if it contains a countable, dense subset).

---

a) and b) are false, right?

In both cases, there are $T_2$ spaces that we want to prove are normal.

Being $T_2$ means that U, V $ \subset $ X open disjoint such that A $ \subset $ U and B $ \subset $ V.But I don't see how to find a closed for any A, B, even with the countable base (first case), as in the case of having a fundamental system of countable neighborhood and being separable (second case).

Comment: A book with hundreds of counterexamples in topology is called (guess what) *Counterexamples in Topology* by Steen & Seebach.  An On-line resource is $\pi$-base at https://topology.jdabbs.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No to both: the [Sorgenfrey plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane) is a counterexample to the second.

The first has the [$\Bbb R_K$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-topology) as a counterexample.

Both are treated in Munkres' text book.